# as_view() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Tags: python, django

help me this problem

url.py

```py
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'login/$',auth_views.LoginView.as_view(template_name="accounts/login.html"),name='login'),
    url(r'logout/$',auth_views.LogoutView.as_view(),name='logout'),
    url(r'signup/$',views.SignUp.as_view(),name='signup'),
]
```

views.py

```py
class SignUp(CreateView):
    form_class = forms.UserCreateForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy("login")
    template_name = 'accounts/signup.html'
```

And this is the error trace back I am getting

```
Traceback: 
File "C:\Users\DELL\anaconda3\envs\MyDjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py",
line 34, in inner response = get_response(request) 
File "C:\Users\DELL\anaconda3\envs\MyDjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py",
line 115, in _get_response response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
File "C:\Users\DELL\anaconda3\envs\MyDjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py",
line 113, in _get_response response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs) –
```

please help

Comment: Can you please provide the *full* traceback?

Comment: This is my code: https://github.com/VanDinhPhu/APP01_24.git

Comment: not the code (per se), but the traceback, the entire error output that shows the call stack frames.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I am not sure but try this in urls.py
some how pattern is
`path('signup/',views.SignUp.as_view( success_url=reverse_lazy('login'), name='signup' ),name='signup')`
`from django.urls import reverse_lazy`